# CKEDITOR 4 text insert issue

Tags: javascript, ckeditor4.x

I am using ckeditor v4.6.2 and need to add text dynamically like below

```
<textarea name="body" id="editor1" class="form-control"></textarea>

CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', customConfig);
var text = "this is home";
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.insertHtml(text);
```

but doesnot work but in browser console I see

```
TypeError: E is undefined
```

Where is my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for CKEditor instance to become ready for interaction. Use [instanceReady](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR.html#event-instanceReady) event:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', customConfig);
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.on('instanceReady', function(evt) {
    evt.editor.insertHtml("this is home");
});
```